# Stream Live Video and relay audio only to icecast2 server

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, icecast

I have a working nginx server which allows me to stream live video from our mobile production system. We also have a radio station on a separate server and would like to stream to both.  But I cannot make it work, nor can I get any logs or error information to explain why.  I have tried nginx config and FFMPEG to try and resolve this.

I have tried various attempts using what I think I understand from other pages online:

```
exec_push FFREPORT=file=ffreport.log:level=48 ffmpeg -i $basename.flv -vn -acodec mp3 rtmp://source:********!!@xxx.xxx.xxx.180:8000/live;
```

Also tried using the simple restream in the nginx conf:

```
application restream {
                    live on;
                    exec_push ffmpeg -i $basename.flv -vn -acodec mp3 rtmp://source:***********@xxx.xxx.xxx.180:8000/live;
                    # push server2:1935
            }
```

I have used the same information on Mixxx Live Broadcast Connection to get the details, thinking I am asking the same thing on the icecast2 server.  Just the source is the nginx server.

This is the full conf on nginx

```
rtmp {

    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4000;

            application live {
                    live on;
                    allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                    allow publish all;
                    allow play all;
                    record all;
                    record_path /usr/local/nginx/flv-streams;
                    record_unique on;
                    exec_record_done ffmpeg -i $basename.flv /usr/local/nginx/html/streams/$basename.mp4;
                    hls on;
                    hls_nested on;
                    hls_path /mnt/hls;
                    hls_fragment 1s;
                    hls_sync 1ms;
                    #exec_push FFREPORT=file=ffreport.log:level=48 ffmpeg -i $basename.flv -vn -acodec mp3 rtmp://source:*************@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/live;
            }
            # Video on Demand
            application streams {
                    play /usr/local/nginx/html/streams/;
            }

            # Restream
            application restream {
                    live on;
                    exec_push ffmpeg -i $basename.flv -vn -acodec mp3 rtmp://source***************@xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/live;
                    # push server2:1935
            }

    }
```

I would like those that can watch any broadcast with video, but if they can only listen, like a radio, I want them to listen via our radio player.  They are two different streams, on different servers.

At the moment I am using software to stream to both and would like to prevent this.

Not found, by my own wording perhaps, any idea on how to do this.

**UPDATE**

With the help from TBR I have managed to get the stream from the Nginx Server going to a new server hosting icecast2.  However, not in the way expected.  It does this 32x faster, so not a stream as such.

```
ffmpeg -i fcpr-1554651146.flv -vn -c:a mp3 icecast://source:password@10.0.0.0:8000/fcprlive.mp3
```

However, I wonder if I have been thinking of this the wrong way.  In my liquidsoap file I have this code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
 # Log dir set("log.file.path","/tmp/basic-radio.log")
 # Music
 myplaylist = mksafe(playlist("/home/offlineftp/playlist"))

 #Live Source
 set("harbor.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")
 live = input.http("http://localhost:8000/fcprlive")
 radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false, [live,plist])

 # Stream it out
 output.icecast(%mp3, host = "localhost", port = 8000,
 password = "pass", mount = "/fcpr")
```

Should I look at using LiquidSoap to pull the stream from Nginx, when live, and if no signal than go to the fallback?

Comment: Zero of the snippets indicate any Icecast or liquidsoap involvement. Would you like to clarify this please?

Comment: Well the icecast2 / liquipdsoap functions are working without any issue, so I didn't want to confuse anyone.   On the Mixxx braodcasting I have the correct settings, which is external, and is working, so I wanted to know how to do the same thing with ffmpeg.  But it is that which I have difficulty.

Comment: What I mean is, I see `ffmpeg` invocations, but they reference a protocol that I'm completely unfamiliar with `rmtp://` or is that a typo and you mean `rtmp://`? – either way, Icecast does **not** support either of them. So what are you trying to do with those ffmpeg invocations? Please explain.

Comment: @TBR really sorry, yes it was a typo.  I was not even sure that should be right, because on Mixxx it uses icecast2, but I beleive that is a rtmp server.

Comment: Icecast is not an RTMP server. I should know, I'm its maintainer. ;-)   You'll want to look up the documentation for FFMPEG's `icecast://` protocol.

Comment: @TBR tried a huge number of alterations, but I am unable to have nginx stream audio to a seperate icecast2 server.   Checking the logs of the icecast server I cannot even see the nginx attempt to connects.   Been working on this for a week and normally I would have found a solution with help.  But I guess it's not possible.  Thank you for your consideration though.

Comment: Have you tried to approach this component wise? First, get a working `ffmpeg` command line and only once that works for ingesting from some input, e.g. file, and sending to Icecast, only then integrating it into the nginx config?

Comment: I am using ffmpeg to convert the flv to a mp4, and move it to a new folder which works, once the stream is finished.  But I dont know how to stream this via the command line, unless I use the flv file which created as soon as the stream starts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took some weeks, but I have managed to get it working.

So what happened:  We use to use two streams from Mixxx and MimoLive, because we wanted a radio station, but sometimes we video.  But this meant I had to transmit twice.  Mixxx was broadcasting audio to icecast. MimoLive was broadcasting  to Nginx Server audio and video.

During mobile broadcasting that was a lot of bandwidth and data.  So I was looking to rely only the audio from the Nginx server, and relay it to the icecast server.  With the help and direction of @TBR, I managed to get this working using this:

```
 exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/fcpr -vn -c:a libmp3lame -f mp3 icecast://source:password@ip.to.ice.cast:8000/live;
```

What I missed was the encoding a .flv into a .mp3, as well as using the correct attributes on the ffmpeg instruction.

It is also worth noting that the icecast server uses Liquidsoap so when no broadcast is being received it reverts back to the playlist.

Hope this might help others looking to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you have an Nginx server that writes to a 'flv' file continuously.

I'd recommend approaching this bit by bit.

## 1. prototype the FFmpeg command that will stream to Icecast *outside of Nginx* to avoid confusion

All you want to do is verify that you can successfully stream audio from a static video file to Icecast and listen to it. It's most likely going to look something like this:

`ffmpeg -i test.flv -vn -c:a libopus icecast://source:password@icecast.example.org:8000/teststream.opus`
or in case of MP3
`ffmpeg -i test.flv -vn -c:a mp3 icecast://source:password@icecast.example.org:8000/teststream.mp3`

You might need to further customize this to your needs, but it should give you the idea of how to start.

#### 2. Integrate into your Nginx setup

You can then put this into your Nginx config and figure out how to make sure it can read the flv file while it's being written to and that it's being executed.
For debugging you might want to redirect STDOUT and STDERR by appending `2>&1 >/tmp/ffmpeg-icecast.log` to your command.

Comment: Is it static, if it is live?  The file is started as I am recording it from within the Nginx Server, and the file exists as soon as the stream starts.  So I would have thought the file was dynamic, as it is increasing in size each second the stream is live ?

Comment: I have updated the question at the bottom.  Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.  The code you gave works on a old file, but it streams it 32x faster so it not eligible, and it ignores the liquid soap fallback, and adds a new mount, rather than replacing it.

Comment: You might want to tackle things one at a time instead of frustrating yourself that it doesn't do **everything** you expected on the first try. – Yes, a growing file that is being written to *should* be usable *if* FFmpeg can find enough information in the header. || To the '32x faster' issue, look at adding `-re`. ( https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#The-reflag ). Please note that Stackoverflow is not about delivering a flawless solution for free. It's about helping everyone with such a problem, including you, to figure it out.

Comment: Hiya, I understand what Stackoverflow is, and your help has been invaluable.  But my question in the comment was more about if I was even going about this the right way.   icecast seems to struggle with LiquidSoap when an external stream is found.  If I used Mixxx LiquidSoap stops when a live stream comes in and moves the user.  Identical I seem unable to do this with Nginx.  Should Icecast2 constantly look for a live stream from the Nginx server, rather than Nginx push to icecast ?